# make the selected drop down value must be sticky

Tags: php

```
$service = CityService::getInstance();
$cities = $service->getAllCities(); 
foreach($cities as $city){
    echo"<option value='".$city->CityID."'>".ucfirst($city->CityName)."</option>";
}
```

here in this code I am getting list from cities , I want to make the selected values sticky in the drop down, where should I apply "selected" ???

Comment: Please, use Google. This question is been answered a million times. You cannot even improve this question.

Comment: I am a beginner, I searched google also, but I couldn't find the solution, if u know please answer..

Comment: See my answer. Also see the link. First hit on Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, your `select` tag has `name="city"`. So then in your `$_POST["city"]` will be the selected city.

So, when you iterate through all the cities, check, is the `$_POST["city"]` (what set by user), is the same, as the current item in the loop:

```
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $selected = '';
    if (!empty($_POST["city"]) && $_POST["city"] == $city->CityID) {
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo"<option value='" . $city->CityID . "'" . $selected . ">" . ucfirst($city->CityName) . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: What do you meand not working? Is your `select name=` city? If not, then change the key of POST variable of course.

Comment: not city, its cityname, even though I changed name its not working

Comment: So you've changed it to `!empty($_POST["cityname"]) && $_POST["cityname"] == $city->CityID`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```
service = CityService::getInstance();
$cities = $service->getAllCities(); 
foreach($cities as $city){
    echo"<option value='".$city->CityID."' selected>".ucfirst($city->CityName)."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Because this code is not good. There is no any condition to check, is the posted value is equal to the actual value in loop.

Comment: This answer was only to show you how you can select an option.

Comment: You asked where you should apply selected. Well, this is an exact answer to your question. If this is not what you are looking for, you should rephrase your question.